# Restore BIP44 HD wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, bip44

I'm newbie in bitcoin development, I'm working on a wallet and I generated addresses using BIP44. Now for restoring my wallet, I followed the example 
[RestoreFromSeed.java](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/examples/RestoreFromSeed.java) it uses `Wallet.fromSeed(netParams, seed);` but it seems to restore BIP32 addresses. Is there a way to restore BIP44 addresses instead? I'm using the 0.14.7 version of bitcoinj. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

BIP44 is a convention about derivation paths. BIP32 gives you an extended master key which you can then combine with a derivation path to get a private key.

So after you get your master key you are probably looking for the key with derivation path `m/44'/0'/0'/0/0`. I am not familiar with bitcoinj or Java but from a quick search it seems that you can find what you need [here](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/crypto/HDUtils.java)